# how to get buffer from Imagemagick image in c++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick library for image manipulation. I need to load a 'bmp' image, convert it to jpeg, load it in a buffer and send it across the network.

However, I am not able to find any supporting function in ImageMagick which can convert and store data in buffer. I am only able to write in file. Tried using `Magick::Blob` but still of no use.

Following code is used to load, convert and write in file:

```
Magick::Image img("Sample.bmp");
img.magick("jpeg");
img.write("Output.jpeg");
```

EDIT:

Used Magick::Blob as:

```
Magick::Blob myBlob;
img.write(&myBlob);
const void *myData = myBlob.data();
```

But here I can't convert myData to `const char*` buffer without any loss.

Comment: What did you try with `Blob` that didn't work ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert to `const char*`? It is a buffer you want to send over a network. No matters whether it is a `void *` or a `char *`. You only need a pointer to the beginning of the buffer, and the size of this buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answers.
My existing socket connection accepts string stream at both ends. That's why I needed `const char*`.
Found conversion function `base64()` in `Magick::Blob` which returns string.
This solved my problem. For reference, the final code becoms:

```
Magick::Image img("Sample.bmp");
Magick::Blob blob; 
img.magick( "JPEG" )
img.write( &blob );
std::string myStr = myBlob.base64();
```

Comment: So bad you did not explain that you needed a character string at the end. Your question is `store data in buffer` not `store data in character stream`...

Answer (score 5):

Did you try :

```
Magick::Image img("Sample.bmp");

Blob blob; 
img.magick("JPEG");
img.write(&blob);

// Then access blob's data with  blob.data()
sendJpegImage(blob.data(), blob.length());
```

With `void sendJpegImage(void* data, size_t length)` being your data sending function.

Answer (score 1):

The <strike>[documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#write)</strike> suggests to `Use to_blob to write to a String` . Did you do that? If so how that did fail?