# How to construct Image from char buffer or string in Magick++

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, magick++

I need to construct an `Image` object from `char *` or `std::string` in Magick++. I've tried both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick, but still can't work it out.

I first create a `Blob` object and use `Image(const Blob &blob_)` construct function to get an `Image`. Here is demo code:

```
//image is of type std::string
size_t len = image.size();
char *buf = new char[len + 1];
strncpy(buf, image.c_str(), len);
Blob blob(buf, len);
Image pic(blob);
```

But when I run it, I got error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorCoder'
  what():  Magick: JPEG datastream contains no image () reported by coders/jpeg.c:344 (JPEGErrorHandler)
Aborted
```

I found something about [obtain string from Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108472/how-to-get-buffer-from-imagemagick-image-in-c). So I created a `Blob` and update it via `base64` method. But an error still occurred.

The only way I could think out is to save the char buffer in a temporary file and reload it via `Image(const std::string &imageSpec_)`. However, this way is really unnecessary in my option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem is data type conversation. We can't convert `char *` to `Blob` directly. I found some demos in GraphicsMagick's source code. They provide the following way:

1. `string` or `char *` => `unsigned char *`
2. `unsigned char *` => `const void *`
3. `const void *` => `Blob`

Then the `Image` construction is OK. Or you can just try

```
Magick::Blob blob(static_cast<const void *>(image.c_str()), len)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I believe there's a typo in your last statement, though: `Magick::Blob blob(static_cast<const void *>(image.c_str()), len)` - Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanBasile Yes, that's a typo. Thank you, I've fixed it.